# How to read and plot time series data files as candlestick chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, time-series

Here is the time series data.
I'd like to read data file and plot it as candle chart.
Actually, I googled to find pyghon logic I want all day long, But I couldn't.
Any comments will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
2011-11-01 9:00:00, 248.50, 248.95, 248.20, 248.70
2011-11-01 9:01:00, 248.70, 249.00, 248.65, 248.85
2011-11-01 9:02:00, 248.90, 249.25, 248.70, 249.15
2011-11-01 9:03:00, 249.20, 249.60, 249.10, 249.60
2011-11-01 9:04:00, 249.55, 249.95, 249.50, 249.60
2011-11-01 9:05:00, 249.60, 249.85, 249.55, 249.75
2011-11-01 9:06:00, 249.75, 250.15, 249.70, 249.85
2011-11-01 9:07:00, 249.85, 250.15, 249.80, 250.15
2011-11-01 9:08:00, 250.10, 250.40, 250.00, 250.15
2011-11-01 9:09:00, 250.20, 250.35, 250.10, 250.20
```

Comment: There is a great example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read in this data set from the clipboard do

```
from pandas import read_clipboard
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
names = ['date', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']
df = read_clipboard(sep=',', names=names, parse_dates=['date'])
df['d'] = df.date.map(date2num)
```

The top-level `pandas.read_csv` function works similarly to `pandas.read_clipboard`, if you have this data sitting in a CSV or some other type of character-delimited file.

Now on to plotting:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, draw
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick

seconds_per_day = 60 * 60 * 24
fig, ax = subplots()
candlestick(ax, df[['d', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']].values, width=1.0 / seconds_per_day)
ax.xaxis_date()
draw()
```

gives

[image]

Comment: As a heads-up this api maybe changing in 1.4, if you use this please comment on https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1920

Comment: looks like this has been deprecated and replaced with `candlestick_ohlc`, but it works basically the same except for the order of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider plotly.
Details on this link: https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/

.
If you want to achieve the same with matplotlib, then check out this link: 
https://pythonprogramming.net/candlestick-ohlc-graph-matplotlib-tutorial/